# Check if any element in an array matches my condition

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I've got an array with 2 values in it. I want to use an `If` statement to see whether any of the values in the array equals the `SelectedValue` of my DropDown.

So far, everything I've tried only gives negative results (only the `Else` condition is reached):

```
Dim twoValues() As String = {"one", "two"}

If Me.ddlDropdown.SelectedValue.ToLower.Equals(twoValues.Any) Then
    'do something
Else
    'do something else
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invert the comparison and use LINQ's [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) method to compare elements of the array to the provided value, until a matching value is found.
Since the comparison needs to be case-insensitive, you can use the overload of [String.Equals()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals) that accepts a [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) argument.

Better avoid [ToLower()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower) without a `CultureInfo` selector when a case-insensitive comparison is needed.
Also, the [InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) may apply or not, depending on the languages involved in the comparison.
If the current language is the local language and cannot be directly associated with the InvariantCulture, use `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` instead. Or build a custom comparer.

```
Dim twoValues As String() = {"one", "two"}
Dim value = Me.ddlDropdown.SelectedValue.ToString()

If twoValues.Any(Function(s) s.Equals(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then
  'do something
Else
   'do something else
End If
```